# Ручное открытие окна в Fancybox

Tags: fancybox

Здравствуйте. Что-то не получается вручную открыть окно в fancybox.
Вот html:

```
<a id="link-choice" href="#choice-after-add-to-cart">В корзину</a>
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="choice-after-add-to-cart">
    <p>Текст в окошке текст в окошке текст в окошке текст в окошке текст в окошке</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Суть в том, что его нужно открывать только при успешной валидации формы. Но fancybox тупо вешается на ссылку и открывает окно при любом нажатии. А мне надо при условии. Просто если форма не заполнена, открывается другое окно (уже готовое).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
jQuery.fancybox( jQuery('#choice-after-add-to-cart').html() );
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно так:

```
jQuery.fancybox('#choice-after-add-to-cart');
```